# How to do $lookup in Mongo based on specific value in a field

Tags: mongodb, conditional-statements, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, lookup

I am new to Mongo and I have a task

I have two collections Collection 1 and Collection 2

Collection 1 :

```
{
{
id :"1a5086e1-c9ce-4c65-a4b3-u753hd7278"
entityId :"https://sxy.co"
providedBy:"text value"
type:"Display"
exhibitCreatedDate"2023-01-13T09:27:04.000561Z"
effectiveDate:"2020",
link_id:"1a5086e1-c9ce-4c65-a4b3-yE46734g6j891"
}
,
{
id :"1a5086e1-c9ce-4c65-oa4b3-u753djf7278"
entityId :"https://sijh.co"
providedBy:"text value"
type:"Actual"
exhibitCreatedDate"2023-01-13T09:27:04.000561Z"
effectiveDate:"2020"
link_id:"1a5086e1-c9ce-4c65-a4b3-yE46734g6j891"
}
};
```

Collection 2:

```
{
{
_id "1a5086e1-c9ce-4c65-a4b3-yE46734g6j891"
telephoneNumber:"+44-20-7424-4200"
faxNumber:"+44-20-7483-2293"
createdDate:"2023-01-13T09:27:04.000255Z"
modifiedDate:"2023-01-13T09:27:04.000255Z"
}


{
_id "1a5086e1-c9ce-4c65-oa4b3-u753djf7278"
type :"test value"
telephoneNumber:"+44-20-7424-4200"
faxNumber:"+44-20-7483-2293"
createdDate:"2023-01-13T09:27:04.000255Z"
modifiedDate:"2023-01-13T09:27:04.000255Z"
}
}
```

I need to perform lookup from collection 1 collection 2 based on link_id and _id
where my scenario is

I have to do lookup when type:"Display" (collection 1)
or to do the lookup from type:"Actual" (collection 1) only when type is not "Display"(collection 1)

Cuurently I am Querying database times and doing Lookup like below isit any possiblilty to active this in single database query

```
db.Collection1.aggregate([
    {
      $match:
        {
            type: "Display"
        }
    },
    { $lookup:
        {
           from: "Collection 2",
           localField: "linkId",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "Detail"
        }
    },
    { $sort :
        { createdDate : -1 }
    }
]).pretty();


db.Collection1.aggregate([
    {
      $match:
        {
            type: "Actual"
        }
    },
    { $lookup:
        {
           from: "Collection 2",
           localField: "linkId",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "Detail"
        }
    },
    { $sort :
        { createdDate : -1 }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What is your expected output?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I have updated the question with currently what I tried and What need to Achieve please provide the answer if you are aware of

Comment: Is the only difference in those two pipelines the value in the leading $match stages? I'm not sure that matches the description you provided. But if the logic is correct then you can combine the pipelines by using `$in` for the leading `$match` and specifying both values